# Compatibility of maxi sized Mega Bloks

Tags: compatibility, clone-brands

Maxi-size Mega Bloks are larger than Duplo. As far as I can tell they have two times the stud pitch and much larger studs:

[image: Maxi-size Mega Bloks]

What, if any, compatibility is there between the maxi-sized Mega Bloks and either Lego elements or the smaller sizes of Mega Bloks?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, maxi sized mega bloks are compatible with LEGO duplo and LEGO system pieces, but only if the duplo piece is 2x2 studs or larger or the LEGO piece is 4x4 or larger. Also, you can only connect LEGO system pieces and duplo pieces to the undersides of maxi size mega bloks.

Answer (score 0):

The other brands generally fit LEGO bricks. What you have and the Duplo bricks work together. I noticed with any brand that isn't LEGO the pieces are compatible, but they are slightly off like they had a problem perfecting the proportions with the Lego brick. They kind of stick sometimes, and sometimes they are loose enough to just fall off.

Comment: Hi Cindy! I have tried to edit your question to make it easier to read, please review it to see if the conveyed intent has remained intact, and edit it yourself if it didn't.

Comment: Hey zovits! Thanks! I didn't realize how many typos I had. I appreciate your help!! 

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Duplo - Maxi Mega Bloks adapter part](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2186167) on Thingiverse, if custom, non-official 3D parts are acceptable.