# Adapters for Lego Duplo and Mega Bloks

Tags: clone-brands, compatibility, duplo

Similar to [this](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9618/compatibility-of-maxi-sized-mega-bloks) question I am interested in combining Duplo Lego with Mega Bloks.
I want to have full compatibility, i.e. being able to put Duplo on top of Mega Bloks, which requires some type of adapter.

I am looking for BUYABLE adapter pieces (not self-made via 3dprinter or such).

**Does anyone know a source?**

---

I found that Lego has a (discontinued) system called "Lego Primo" with similar round studs. It does have adapter blocks for Duplo (marked with red rectangle):

[image]

**Can anyone confirm that these do / do not fit the Mega Bloks studs?**

Although they are discontinued, they can still be bought used. So if they fit it would be an option for me.

---

2. There is an unconventional type of adapter being sold on [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/403461040983) (seems to be just a single offer, used):

[image]

**Has anyone ever seen these somehwere else? Maybe even in real life?** They do not look 3d-printed, they look injection molded (like Lego and Mega Bloks). So there might be someone producing them (or having produced them) commercially...

Comment: I've linked to the eBay item your picture comes from, in order to let others see the whole listing with all images. Note though that the listing explicitly mentions how _"They are extremely hard to find."_ I can easily imagine someone having set up an injection molding line for these parts, and only producing a handful of them before getting hit by C&D letters from both TLG and Mattel - thus limiting the availability of these parts severely.

Comment: I have several of the second (white) adapter you show in the photo, from my original 1990s Mega Bloks sets. I have the original Ritvik Mega Bloks (the only size now sold) as well as a Ritvik Mega Bloks set that is almost identical to Duplo blocks (sold in the early 90s, mine are marked 1992), with the white adapters made by Ritvik.

Answer (score 6):

Primo and Mega Bloks are **not** compatible.

The Primo piece loosely fits on a Mega Blok piece:

[image: Primo and Mega Bloks]

But the Mega Blok piece does not fit on the Primo stud.

[image: Primo and Mega Bloks]

As for the adapters in your second photo, I have seen them many times in used toy collections I've bought; unfortunately, I don't think I've ever seen them new in the package to give you a specific reference on how to buy them. But I've always assumed they were an actual Mega Brands product.

I have a 2x2 (or 1x1) and 2x4 (or 1x2) in front of me. The smaller says **430** and **© 1988**. The larger says **439** and **PAT PEND** and **© 1988** and (tellingly) **Ritvik**. ([Ritvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkbi_AG_v_Ritvik_Holdings_Inc) was the maker of Mega Bloks.)